# Manifest 'https://www.example.com/manifest.json' is not http 200

Tags: json, mobile-website, progressive, web-manifest

I am trying to create progressive app for my website. I created the manifest.json file and uploaded in server. Then I gave a link for the manifest file in my home page. The manifest file is proper but when i try to check it using my site url then its giving an error as "Manifest 'https://www.example.com/manifest.json' is not http 200"

Comment: What response header are you seeing when calling the manifest file in your browser? (Using the "net" tab in the browser's developer tools)

Comment: Thanks #Pekka for the response....I cant see any status related to the manifest file

Comment: Every request in a web browser has a response status code, always. Open your browser's developer tools, open the manifest URL, and look what happens in the "net" tab.

Comment: Ya but still its not coming...is it bcoz its a json file?

Comment: In documentation its told that to link the manifest.json I have to insert  <link href="/Content/manifest.json" rel="manifest"> where /Content/manifest.json is the location where i have uploaded the file but its not working when i am checking for manifest validation

Comment: This is what the "net" tab should look like in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/images/network-panel.png

Comment: Ya i understood i am not getting the manifest file status in the list..anyways thanks a lot.. i will check..

Comment: Open the manifest file explicitly. Reload if necessary, with the developer tools open.

Comment: Its telling file not found but i have the file in the server at that particular location. All other links are working except that

Comment: Then that's the problem you want to solve... you could take a look at the server's error logs to see whether they contain a clue.

Comment: ya problem is that when i am using this link "ftp://abc@example.com/test.example.com/Content/themes/base/manifest.json" which is nothing but the ftp link for the file, to open the file then i can view but if i try to view using "test.example.com/Content/themes/base/manifest.json" only its telling file not found

Comment: mobile.twitter.com also have the same problem right now

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to configure the application/json MIME type in your web server. It is probably blocked by default for security reasons.